# xaml Translate column names in Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I use a `DataGrid` which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>` like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" />
```

The column names in the grid are the same as the names of the properties in my class `Item`s. How can I change these names, e.g. based on current culture?

My `Item` class has the properties:

```
public object ThisIsProperty1{get;set;}
public object Property2{get;set;}
```

My column names in the grid get the name "ThisIsProperty1" and "Property2", but I want to set customized names like "P1" and "Prop 2".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please elaborate its not exactly clear what you want to do...maybe geve an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to override some Headers, try the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Desired Header" Binding="{Binding SomePropToOverride}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Another Header" Binding="{Binding SomeOtherPropToOverride}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you only want specific columns to show you can add `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` to the `DataGrid`

You can find a more in depth tutorial [here](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to handle localisation is to make all strings ( that will need translating ) a resource in a resource dictionary. I usually have a "base" default English resourcedictionary. Then a resource dictionary per other language. Merge in the appropriate language.  I then use dynamicresource to reference the string by key hence roughly:

```
Header="{DynamicResource Property2HeaderKey}"
```

You can merge in "loose" uncompiled resource dictionaries off disk which allows you to decouple easily. When you have someone wants an unusual language you can deliver their file separately and even after installation if necessary.

You can alternatively store a resource dictionary as a string in a database and xamlreader.load it into a resource dictionary dynamically.

Quite often you have an "admin" or super user area of an app which has functionality it's ok if it's still presented in English so a language resource dictionary can be a subset of the default English one.